# How to get the parents siblings content Jquery

Tags: jquery, siblings

Below, is my code. My goal is, when the user clicks the `<a>` tag which is in 'siblings_2'. I want to alert the 'Hello' which is in 'sibling_1' content. How can I achieve this?

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="sibling_1">
        <div class="selections">
           <p>Hello</p>
           <p>How Are You?</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sibling_2">
        <a href="">Click Me!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various ways to achieve it and one way is:

```
$("div.sibling_2 a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = $(this).parent().prev().find("div.selections p:eq(0)").text();
    alert(text);
})
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t5WNw/)**

Answer (score 1):

The following works

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).closest('.parent').find('p:first-child').text());
    return false;
})
```

http://jsbin.com/uvevek/3/edit

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function() {
    $('.sibling_2 a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($('.sibling_1').text());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/p9mEx/